# String.CompareTo with case

Tags: c#, .net

Sample code to illustrate:

```
    int res1 = "a".CompareTo("A");  // res1 = -1
    int res2 = "ab".CompareTo("A");  // res2 = 1
```

I'm seeing `res1 = -1`, and `res2 = 1` at the end, which was a bit unexpected. 
I thought `res1` would return 1, since on an *ASCII* chart "A" (0x41) comes before "a" (0x61).

Also, it seems strange that for `res2`, the length of the string seems to make a difference. i.e. if "a" comes before "A" (as `res1 = -1` indicates), then I would have thought that "a"withAnythingAfterIt would also come before "A"withAnythingAfterIt.

Can someone shed some light? 
Thanks.

Comment: shorter strings are considers smaller, so "a", "b"...."z", "aa"

Comment: You seem to be expecting CompareTo to do an ordinal comparison, which is not what it does. Did you consult the documentation for [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx)? There is a static method, string.CompareOrdinal for performing the kind of comparison you want.

Comment: @mikez yes, i did read the documentation for CompareTo. I guess i misunderstood what "culture sensitive comparison" means. Thanks.

Comment: @mikez is there some place that documents the "culture sensitive comparison" rules for specific cultures? e.g. like the fact that lower case comes before upper case in res1.

Comment: @Moe Yes those are the magic words. Actually that's good question. I can't seem to find any specific documentation that 'a' would come before 'A' in a culture sensitive comparison, but it is mentioned in several examples, for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx). The [Windows API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318144(v=vs.85).aspx) also gives you a feel for what kinds of comparisons are possible (although not what the default option is in .NET).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `String.CompareTo(string)` does a culture sensitive comparison, using its sort order. In fact it calls `CultureInfo` to do the job as we can see in the source code:

```
public int CompareTo(String strB) {
    if (strB==null) {
        return 1;
    }

    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(this, strB, 0);
}
```

Your current culture puts 'A' after 'a' in the sort order, since it would be a tie, but not after 'ab' since clearly 'ab' comes after either 'a' or 'A' in most sort orders I know. It's just the tie breaking mechanism doing its work: when the sort order would be the same, use the ordinal value!

Comment: thanks, i think the "tie breaking mechanism" idea is the key to understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

**From MSDN**

Definition

> Compares this instance with a specified Object and indicates whether
>   this instance precedes, follows, or appears in the same position in
>   the sort order as the specified Object.

Note

> The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or
>   alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary
>   purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are
>   equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the
>   Equals method.

`CompareTo` is an instance method.

If the first string is bigger, the result is 1. If the first string is smaller, the result is -1. If both strings are equal, the result is 0. The number essentially indicates how much "larger" the first string is.

```
Console.WriteLine("a".CompareTo("A")); // -1
Console.WriteLine("ab".CompareTo("A")); // 1
Console.WriteLine("a".CompareTo("a")); // 0
Console.WriteLine("ab".CompareTo("AB")); // -1
Console.WriteLine("A".CompareTo("a")); // 1
Console.WriteLine("AB".CompareTo("ab")); // 1
Console.WriteLine("A".CompareTo("A")); // 0
```

Comment: `"a".CompareTo("a")` shouldn't return 1, on my machine it returns `0` as expected.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks buddy! May be, it was typing mistake at that time but yes it should return "0". I edited my answer.